# svg animation bug (out of mask/clip-path lines)

Tags: animation, svg, css-animations, clip-path

[line is out of mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXTFo.png)

There are lines out of clip-path while animation is running (when the svg have certain width or scaling)
The animation is transform: translate() of the group inside clip-path group.
Maybe someone have dealt with this problem, help pls (

Comment: Hi. To be able to help, you need to provide some of your code. Ideally in the form of [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.